# What is RNA Engineering

Tags: rna, biotechnology

I've been hearing the term passed around, and my own [research](http://newscenter.lbl.gov/2015/04/07/possible-new-rna-engineering-tool/) has led me to some very [high-level papers](http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v12/n10/full/nmeth.3486.html) which propose new tools for accomplishing RNA engineering.

From the abstract of one of the above linked papers:

> These methods advance our ability to develop broadly applicable genetic tools and to elucidate the underlying sequence-structure-function relationships that empower rational design of complex biomolecules.

It seems as though we are edging close to designing fine-tuned lifeforms. It's easy to jump to exorbitant conclusions, so I'd like to make sure I understand what this is all about.

My questions are:

1. What exactly is RNA engineering and what can it accomplish (in plain english)
2. What are the implications of the advent of RNA engineering tools